# Have vector<object>; return vector<object.member> without copying

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a std::vector of objects:

```
std::vector<Character>
```

where

```
class Character{
....
Vector position;
Vector velocity;
Vector force;
double mass;
};
```

I need only particular member values (positions) to draw my scene.
Is there any fast way to access a certain member in vector of objects?
I would rather avoid loops like

```
std::vector<Vector> tmp;
for(int i=0; i<vect.size(); i++)
    tmp.push_back(vect[i].position);
```

because I don't see the point in copying elements so often, especially when there's a lot of them.

Comment: Why are you creating a `tmp` copy if you don't want to copy?

Comment: @Jefffrey That's the code bit that follows "I would rather avoid loops like"...

Comment: Still, why are you even mentioning it? Also "Is there any fast way to access a certain member in vector of objects?" -- is a very broad question. Access members of the vector stored where? From where? What troubles are you having?

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about performance, i.e. overhead of caching big objects (like `Character`) when only a small one (`Vector`) is needed, you should consider changing your design from *array of structure* (AoS) to *structure of arrays* (SoA):

```
class Characters {
  std::vector<Vector> positions;
  std::vector<Vector> velocities
  std::vector<Vector> forces;
  std::vector<double> masses;
  ...
};
```

and define some iterator-like class to represent a single character (of course this must be a `friend` of `Characters`)

```
class Character {
  Characters* const C;
  std::size_t       I;
public:
  Vector const&position() const { return C->positions[I]; }
  Vector &position() { return C->positions[I]; }
  ...
};
```

This will indeed speed up things.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function by reference generates no copies:

```
void Draw(vector<Character>& characters) {
  // Render from the referenced vector, no copies made
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  vector<Character> characters;

  // Generate characters in vector

  Draw(characters);

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT after comment:**

```
class GraphicalContext {
  // Add needed stuff
};

class Drawable {
  virtual ~Drawable() {}
  virtual void Draw(GraphicalContext& gc) = 0;
};

class Tree : public Drawable {
  void Draw(GraphicalContext& gc) {
    // Draw the tree
  }
};

class Character : public Drawable {
  void Draw(GraphicalContext& gc) {
    // Draw the character
  }
};

typedef vector<Drawable*> Objects_t;

void RenderWorld(GraphicalContext& gc, Objects_t& objects) {
  Objects_t::iterator iter = objects.begin();
  for(; iter != objects.end(); ++iter) {
    (*iter)->Draw(gc);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Objects_t objects;

  // Insert objects into objects vector

  GraphicalContext gc;

  RenderWorld(gc, objects);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That I know, the problem is I have Draw(vector<Vector>& vect) and I call it from different classes, so that would be Draw(vector<Character>&) and Draw(vector<Tree>&) and I don't want to have multiple Draw's

Comment: @4gn3s That is something different than you described in your question. I've modified my answer.